# IntelliJ how to do Search in files containing text like Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea, find

my project has file with text "CDSettlementPrintingEnquiryComponent", I want to search which files contain this text in IntelliJ 2020.3, but fail, how to do this in Intellij Community 2020.3?

I try Find in Files>Directory tab also, all my files in under CFMS directlry, but again, IntelliJ still said nothing found...why?

[image]

[image]

Also, I cannot find the "Find in Path" menu mentioned in
[Find the search string in a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)

Comment: There is no "Printing" just "CDSettlementEnquiryComponent"

Comment: yes, reupload the correct image now, thx

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: try but no luck, anyway, seems IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition don't support javascript/typescript
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. It works fine with Community Edition on my side. Is it reproducible with some new sample project (e.g. with one directory and one file in it)?

Comment: I have this same problem. The "search everywhere" function finds hardly anything. I'm using Ultimate 2020.3. Tried invalidating caches, recreating projects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the reason, I check the following website

[Choose Your Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

and it said IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition don't support javascript/Typescript

Comment: It should not be the reason. Search should still work. Autocompletion, refactoring etc might not be available in community edition for .js/.ts